# S3 Ruby SDK List Only Objects Directly under a prefix?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to get a single level of objects under a prefix in an S3 bucket. There are a LARGE number of objects in the bucket so I want to iterate over each folder under a specific prefix. Here's my code so far:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

region = 'us-west-1'
bucket_name = 'my-example-bucket'
prefix = 'test1'
delimiter = '/'

s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: region)
resp = s3_client.list_objects_v2(bucket: bucket_name, prefix: prefix, delimiter: prefix + delimiter)
obj_list = []
resp.contents.each do |c|
  p c
  break
end
```

When I run this I get a single object that's 4 levels deep inside of my prefix.

There are 243 folders under the prefix. I only want these 243 and nothing else.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First you should use prefix='test1/' and delimiter='/'.

However you will get nothing in contents. A folder in S3 is just another prefix so what you can do is iterate over the prefixes.

```
region = 'us-west-1'
bucket_name = 'my-example-bucket'
prefix = 'test1/'

objs = s3_client.list_objects_v2(bucket: bucket_name, prefix: prefix, delimiter: '/')

objs.common_prefixes.map(&:prefix).each do |prefix|
  current_objs = s3_client.list_objects_v2(bucket: bucket_name, prefix: prefix, delimiter: '/')
  p current_objs.contents # you will get nothing here again if all you have inside the folders is some other folders
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work as intended. This still returns me results with objects more than 1 level down.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a collection of just the "folder" names under the prefix `test1`.

In other words, if we had these nested prefixes in the s3 bucket: `test1/stuff/`, `test1/stuff/more/`, `test1/other/`, the result should be: `["stuff", "other"]`.

```
bucket_name = "my-example-bucket"
prefix = "test1/"
delimiter = "/"
   
object_list = S3_CLIENT.list_objects(bucket: bucket_name, prefix: prefix, delimiter: delimiter)

object_list.common_prefixes.each_with_object([]) do |common_prefix, memo|
  
  # match the prefix one level under our desired prefix while filtering out files at that level
  next unless match_prefix = common_prefix.prefix.match(/#{prefix}\/(.+)\//)[1]
  
  # Skip it if we already have collected that prefix
  next if memo.include?(match_prefix)

  memo << match_prefix
end
```